# Python csv.DictReader

Tags: python, csv

I was trying different codes with csv.DictReader to read csv file into a variable.

```
#option 1
dna = []
with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as file:
    dna = csv.DictReder(file)
print(dna)
#output = csv.DictReader object at 0x123

#option 2
dna = []
with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in reader:
        dna.append(row)
print(dna)
#output = csv in array
```

I have a few questions about this code.

1. Why does option 1 return an address?
2. Why is reader needed in option 2 for this code to work?
3. Some codes I've seen doesn't include "r" but still work the same. Why is that?

Thank you!

Comment: `csv.dictReader()` returns a class instance. The class implements the iteration protocol, so you can loop over it with `for`.

Comment: Use `dna = list(csv.DictReader(file))` to convert it to a list in one step.

Comment: `"r"` is the default mode for `open`, so you don't need to include it explicitly.

Comment: "Why does option 1 return an address?" It does not return an address. Note, you seem to be talking about what is *printed to the screen*. In that case, the default representation of an object is printed to the screen, in this case, of a `csv.DictReader` object.

Answer (score 0):

1. `DictReader` is a class, when you instantiate it `DictReader()` you have an instance of that class, which is located somewhere in memory
2. The class **helps** you to read the csv, it is designed to gives you the content if you iterate over it, you can so it in one line with

   ```
   dna = list(csv.DictReader(file))
   ```
3. `r` mode for read, is the default one, so put or not is same